# Running CodeIgniter Project locally on Windows

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

My CodeIgniter project is located in

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/CodeIgniter/myproject
```

And I am using `Xampp`.

I set a base URL like this but it is not working.

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:3000/myproject';
```

How I can run this project locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick debug time.

So what happens if you just use `http://localhost` in the url?

You should see whatever is in `C:/xampp/htdocs/`. So if you have a index.php in there, that should show up. If you don't have an index.php, then create one and see what happens.

Unless you have done "other things" in your setup, your Server Document Root will be C:/xampp/htdocs/. So it will be expecting your projects to be under that folder.

Now, you have decided to put your project under     **C:/xampp/htdocs/Project/CodeIgniter/myproject**

So you would need to use **http://localhost/Project/CodeIgniter/myproject**
Do you get the Codeigniter welcome ( NOTE: if you haven't altered the default route)

**A very quick fix,** using your current settings, would be to relocate your project to 
**C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject** as this is where the server is expecting to see it with the URL you are using.

What happens?

Personally, I never use localhost and create a virtual host which from memory XAMPP allows you to do from its management window. That way your project files can be located anywhere as long as the server knows where to find them. I will leave that as a project for you to look at.

Comment: Locating source code to C:/xampp/htdocs/myproject didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

How does your .htaccess file looks like?
It should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /myproject
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Comment: @codermouse - you are very cooperative. You wrote this in your original post. What does it mean "it's not working"? What does your application or apache log says?

Comment: Updating .htaccess file as you mentioned was not helpful.

Comment: @codermouse - your comment wasn't helpful either. You wrote "I set a base URL like this but it is not working." - what's in your logs? What does it mean it is not working?

Answer (score -1):

Replace

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:3000/myproject';
```

To

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$config['base_url'] = preg_replace('@/+$@','',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'])).'/';
```

And your .htaccess file should look like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|install|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score -1):

check your project path 
and site base url

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/your_project_path/';
```

if you have port

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:3000/myproject';
```

in application/config/config.php
after that index.php is run

and set database connection if you want to conncet db 
in your_project/application/config/database.php

```
db['default']['username'] ='your_db_root_user';
$db['default']['password'] = 'your_db_root_password';
$db['default']['database'] = 'database_name'; 
 // The following values can probably stay the same.
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost:3000';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = "";
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = true;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = "";
$db['default']['char_set'] = "utf8";
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = "utf8_general_ci";
```